# Spy chained functions in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, spy, pytest-mock

I am trying to unit test a function that is calling two other functions internally. It looks like the following

```
class A(BaseClass):
    def functionA(self, var_a, var_b):
        return self.another_fn_a(var_a).another_fn_b(var_b)
```

`another_fn_a` and `another_fn_b` are part of the base class that this class is extending and return the same class itself.

Now, I am trying to test my `functionA` to see that its calling the other two functions with the right argument. I am able to spy on `another_fn_a`, but the spy on `another_fn_b` doesn't seem to be working. My test looks like the following

```
def test_will_funcationA(mocker):
    test_obj = ClassA()

    spy_a = mocker.spy(test_obj, 'another_fn_a')
    spy_b = mocker.spy(test_obj, 'another_fn_b')

    test_obj.functionA("var_1", "var_2")

    spy_a.assert_called_once_with("var_1")
    spy_b.assert_called_once_with("var_2")
```

The first assert seems to be working, however, for the second assert I get Assertion Error saying that another_fn_b wasn't called.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `another_fn_a` return? Does it return `self` or some other object?

Comment: it returns another object of type `BaseClass`. So does `another_fn_b`

Comment: So then `test_obj.another_fn_b` actually isn't called.

Comment: then how do I check that `another_fn_b` is being called?

Comment: i tried `spy_b = mocker.spy(test_obj.another_fn_a("var_1"), 'another_fn_b')`. But that doesnt seem to be working either